# Duplicate field in response symfony2 entity

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine, entity

I am using symfony 2, I have one field in database "**old_status**". I want to change it to "**status**" field (change in both database + entity. I changed it because It is making the developer confuse)

```
   /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     *
     * @Expose
     */
    private $status;
```

So in the response it will change to "**status**". But I don't want to change the contract. I want to show both of "**old_status**" and "**status**" fields but with same value. So the current partner will continue use "old_status" until they move to new field. The new partner will use "status".

I don't want add more field in database, I want to handler it by use entity.

Can I do it with entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply leave the old getter and make them both new and old methods use the new field name `status`.

something like:

```
public function getStatus() {
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @deprecated Renamed to getStatus
 */
public function getOldStatus() {
    return $this->status;
}
```

You can do a similar thing with other methods, like setters, if needed.

Since `$status` is a private field, it's just a matter of public interface.